# Homepage Layout is changed automatically

Tags: wordpress, layout

My homepage was working fine till yesterday and suddenly its layout is changed automatically. It has white space at left and right side of the contents. These changes happened only on homepage, other pages are absolutely fine.

Can someone please help me?
[image: screenshot of homepage]

Comment: what's happen in console?

Comment: Is the live domain the one in your search bar? I cannot reproduce your bug on that domain myself.